# Configure RouteConfig in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I use Vue.js 2.3, I want to define my own class for active href.

I saw 'linkActiveClass' option in the doc, but I can't figure out how to use it. I tried directly in code :

```
<router-link :to="{path : 'about', linkActiveClass: 'active', exact: true}" class="item" :linkActiveClass="active"><i class="icon talk"></i> About</router-link>
```

It doesn't work. I think I can define it in RouteConfig, but how to do that ? I see nothing in doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using `active-class`

```
<router-link :to="{path : 'about', exact: true}" class="item" active-class="active"><i class="icon talk"></i> About</router-link>
```

Comment: Nice it works ! How do you know ? Didn't find in the doc ?

Comment: it's there actually https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-link.html. `linkActiveClass` is the field you use to configure router, but in the component `router-link` you should use `active-class`